# Scrapy not scraping if one item missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I built my first scray spider in several hours for the last two days but i am stuck right now - the main purpose i wanted to achieve is to extract all data to later filter it in csv. Now, the real crucial data for me (Companies without! webpages) is dropped because scrapy can't find the xpath i provided if an item has a homepage. I tried an if statement here, but its not working.

Example website: https://www.achern.de/de/Wirtschaft/Unternehmen-A-Z/Unternehmen?view=publish&item=company&id=1345

I use xPath selector: `response.xpath("//div[@class='cCore_contactInformationBlockWithIcon cCore_wwwIcon']/a/@href").extract()`

Example non-website: https://www.achern.de/de/Wirtschaft/Unternehmen-A-Z/Unternehmen?view=publish&item=company&id=1512

Spider Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class AchernSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'achern'
allowed_domains = ['www.achern.de']
start_urls = ['https://www.achern.de/de/Wirtschaft/Unternehmen-A-Z/']



def parse(self, response):
    for href in response.xpath("//ul[@class='cCore_list cCore_customList']/li[*][*]/a/@href"):
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback= self.scrape)

def scrape(self, response):
    #Extracting the content using css selectors
    print("Processing:"+response.url)
    firma = response.css('div>#cMpu_publish_company>h2.cCore_headline::text').extract()
    anschrift = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'cCore_addressBlock_address')]/text()").extract()
    tel = response.xpath("//div[@class='cCore_contactInformationBlockWithIcon cCore_phoneIcon']/text()").extract()
    mail = response.xpath(".//div[@class='cCore_contactInformationBlock']//*[contains(text(), '@')]/text()").extract()
    web1 = response.xpath("//div[@class='cCore_contactInformationBlockWithIcon cCore_wwwIcon']/a/@href").extract()
    if "http:" not in web1:
        web = "na"
    else:
        web = web1

    row_data=zip(firma,anschrift,tel,mail,web1) #web1 must be changed to web but then it only give out "n" for every link
    #Give the extracted content row wise
    for item in row_data:
        #create a dictionary to store the scraped info
        scraped_info = {
            'Firma' : item[0],
            'Anschrift' : item[1] +' 77855 Achern',
            'Telefon' : item[2],
            'Mail' : item[3],
            'Web' : item[4],
        }

        #yield or give the scraped info to scrapy
        yield scraped_info
```

So overall it should export the DROPPED items even "web" is not there..

Hope someone can help, greetings S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
response.css(".cCore_wwwIcon > a::attr(href)").get()
```

gives you a `None` or the website address, then you can use `or` to provide a default:

```
website = response.css(".cCore_wwwIcon > a::attr(href)").get() or 'na'
```

Also, I refactored your scraper to use css selectors. Note that I've used `.get()` instead of `.extract()` to get a single item, not a list, which cleans up the code quite a bit.

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class AchernSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'achern'
    allowed_domains = ['www.achern.de']
    start_urls = ['https://www.achern.de/de/Wirtschaft/Unternehmen-A-Z/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for url in response.css("[class*=cCore_listRow] > a::attr(href)").extract():
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.scrape)

    def scrape(self, response):
        # Extracting the content using css selectors
        firma = response.css('.cCore_headline::text').get()
        anschrift = response.css('.cCore_addressBlock_address::text').get()
        tel = response.css(".cCore_phoneIcon::text").get()
        mail = response.css("[href^=mailto]::attr(href)").get().replace('mailto:', '')
        website = response.css(".cCore_wwwIcon > a::attr(href)").get() or 'na'

        scraped_info = {
            'Firma': firma,
            'Anschrift': anschrift + ' 77855 Achern',
            'Telefon': tel,
            'Mail': mail,
            'Web': website,
        }
        yield scraped_info


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = CrawlerProcess()
    p.crawl(AchernSpider)
    p.start()
```

output:

```
with website:
{'Firma': 'Wölfinger Fahrschule GmbH', 'Anschrift': 'Güterhallenstraße 8 77855 Achern', 'Telefon': '07841 6738132', 'Mail': 'info@woelfinger-fahrschule.de', 'Web': 'http://www.woelfinger-fahrschule.de'}

without website:
{'Firma': 'Zappenduster-RC Steffen Liepe', 'Anschrift': 'Am Kirchweg 16 77855 Achern', 'Telefon': '07841 6844700', 'Mail': 'Zappenduster-Rc@hotmail.de', 'Web': 'na'}
```

Comment: Damn, that was fast. Thank you very much.. it's just "OR" - it worked like a charm!

Comment: Gern geschehen :)